# How can I know which application is asking me for my password?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I just updated Ubuntu. And immediately after I logged into my Ubuntu session, I got a prompt asking me for my password with the User Name field automatically filled with my Gmail email.

How can I figure out which application is asking me for my password before I input it?

As you can see from the screenshot below, there's no info whatsoever about the application that triggered the dialog.

[image: Password prompt with no info]

Comment: do you have chrome services running in the background?

Comment: "without any action from my side" ... you logged in. A number of things happen at login: email clients startup, GNOME's integration with online accounts for calendars, etc. activates, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the `apport-bug` command to figure this out.

I ran `apport-bug -w` and then clicked on the dialog afterwards. This generated the following bug report which contains the path to the executable at `/usr/bin/gnome-calendar`.

[image: Apport Report]

Comment: It's a shame that this is still not fixed 5 years later.